# Recent progress in the irrationality measure of $\pi$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, pi, irrationality-measure

**The context.**

For any real number $x$, let's define the quantity

$$\mu(x):=\sup\left\{\mu\in\mathbb R_+\, \text{there is an infinity of $(p,q)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb N$ such that}\ 0<\left\vert x-\frac pq\right\vert<\frac 1{q^{\mu}}\right\},$$

and let's call it the *irrationality measure* of $x$.

We know that

$$\mu(\pi)\leqslant 8.016$$

thanks to M. Hata (1992).

**The question.**

We can read on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) that

\begin{equation}
\mu(\pi)\leqslant 7.6063,
\end{equation}

but this is provided without any reference.

> 1. Do you know any article where I could find a mention of this result?
> 2. Does this bound have been improved?

Comment: [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) has a reference for the smaller bound: "Salikhov, V. Kh. "On the Irrationality Measure of pi." Usp. Mat. Nauk 63, 163-164, 2008. English transl. in Russ. Math. Surv 63, 570-572, 2008." I don't know if there's been any progress since 2008.

Comment: @Micah That looks like a potential answer to the question to me.

Comment: @Micah: I don't believe a better value is currently known, because if there were a better value, then I'm sure it would turn up in the google search [Salikhov + "on the irrationality measure of"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Salikhov+%22on+the+irrationality+measure+of%22&filter=0) ([corresponding google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?lookup=0&q=Salikhov+%22On+the+Irrationality+Measure+of%22)). Also, this is the best value mentioned in Marko Leinonen's 2017 Ph.D. dissertation [**On Various Irrationality Measures**](http://jultika.oulu.fi/files/isbn9789526217031.pdf).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thanks! That sounds good enough for an answer to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Salikhov proved the smaller bound in: "Salikhov, V. Kh. "On the Irrationality Measure of pi." [Usp. Mat. Nauk 63, 163-164, 2008](https://doi.org/10.4213/rm9175). English transl. in [Russ. Math. Surv 63, 570-572, 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/RM2008v063n03ABEH004543)." as referenced, e.g., on [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html).

Zeilberger and Zudlin have improved Salikhov's bound to $7.1032\dots$, [here](https://msp.org/moscow/2020/9-4/p06.xhtml) (or the preprint is freely readable [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.06345.pdf)). As of January 2023, this appears to be the best-known result.

Comment: It is now superseded by 7.103205334137..., according to mathworld and this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.06345

Comment: @GeorgeLowther: Fantastic, thanks!

Comment: @Micah The 7.1032... paper has now been published: https://msp.org/moscow/2020/9-4/p06.xhtml. Here's the website of an author: https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/pimeas.html