# Convergency of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\csc(n)}{n!}$

Tags: trigonometric-series

I am stuck on how to prove the convergency of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\csc(n)}{n!}.$$
It seems like that the series converges to approximately $2.85$, but I have no idea how to show whether the series converges or not. I know that there are techniques such as the ratio test, the integral test, the $n^{th}$ term test, but I still do not know how to approach the problem.

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: I don't think this converges ... $\csc(n)$ can be arbitrarily large *if you choose the integer $n$ carefully to be very close to a multiple of $\pi$. If you look at the graph of $\csc(n)$ over reals, it has asymptotes at every integer multiple of $\pi$ edit:clarified, but turns out this guess was wrong anyway!

Comment: That doesn't mean it doesn't converge. Search the flint hill series for an example of an open problem.

Comment: $n!$ grows faster than any polynomial, so the given series is clearly convergent, since the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is finite.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio very interesting, I had never heard of irrationality measure. It's also interesting that the bound is still being improved even in the last year!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ [has a finite irrationality measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2777907/recent-progress-in-the-irrationality-measure-of-pi), in particular there are a finite number of $\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$ \left|\pi - \frac{p}{q}\right|\leq \frac{1}{q^{10}}\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad d(p,\pi\mathbb{Z})\leq\frac{1}{q^9} $$
and for any sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have
$$ \left|\sin(n)\right|\geq \tfrac{2}{\pi}d(n,\pi\mathbb{Z})\geq 2\pi^8\cdot\frac{1}{n^9}. $$
Since the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^9}{n!}$ is convergent, the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n!\sin(n)}$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: For my own knowledge, what is $d(p,\pi \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @NickGuerrero: the distance of $p$ from $\pi \mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $$\min\left(p-\pi\left\lfloor\frac{p}{\pi}\right\rfloor,\pi-p+\pi\left\lfloor\frac{p}{\pi}\right\rfloor\right).$$

Comment: So the absolute difference* between $p$ and the nearest integer multiple of $\pi$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: exactly.

Comment: From that Wikipedia link it seems that at most finitely many $\frac{p}q$ with $|\pi - \frac{p}q| \le \frac1{q^{10}}$ exist, which is enough for this problem. Stating that none exist is false, as $p=3, q=1$ shows.

Comment: @Ingix: correct indeed, answer fixed.

Comment: Reminds me of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3\sin^2n}$$ mentioned in an answer in the thread [Are there any series whose convergence is unknown?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/)

Comment: Why is there a $\pi^8$ factor?

Comment: @Szeto $\frac{2}{\pi}d(n, \pi\mathbb{Z}) \geq \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{\big\lfloor \frac{n}{\pi}\big\rfloor^9}\geq  2\pi^8\cdot \frac{1}{n^9}$, where in the first inequality irrationality of $\pi$ was used.