# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\csc n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know there is a closed form for
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n!},$$
and I am wondering if there is also a closed form for
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\csc n}{n!}.$$
**My Attempt:**
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\csc n}{n!}$$
$$= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2i}{(e^{in}-e^{-in})n!}}$$
$$ = 2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\left(\frac{e^{2in}}{e^{in}}-\frac{1}{e^{in}}\right)n!}}$$
$$= 2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{in}}{(e^{2in}-1)n!}}$$
I know the taylor series
$$ e^x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{n}}{n!}},$$
but I don't know how to continue the problem anymore.

To see whether the series converges, please visit [Convergency of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\csc(n)}{n!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930802/convergency-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cscnn)

Comment: I think a closed form is unlikely.  Even to prove the sum converges is not obvious (relying on an estimate of how well $\pi$ can be approximated by rationals).

Comment: I think so too, but maybe there is one. I also added a link that is about the convergency of the series.