# Behavior of an Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, trigonometric-series

I've been studying infinite series recently and believe I came across a counterintuitive (at least to me) result in the past from a textbook that I can't seem to find now. Is it possible to show $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\csc(n)}{n}$$ converges? I actually think the result I saw was something along the lines of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\csc(\sqrt{3}\, n)}{n}$ being a convergent series, though I don't remember the exact form and my internet searches haven't turned up anything that has been particularly helpful with this problem.

Plugging the series into WolframAlpha as is shows that it diverges, but computing various values for finite series shows that the value stabilizes around $-77.5$ ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+csc%28n%29%2Fn+from+n%3D1+to+n%3D3000) is the sum from $n=1$ to $n=3000$) -- I computed various values up to $n=5000$

I did find related series (such as the [Flint Hills Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html) and the [Cookson Hills Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CooksonHillsSeries.html)) and this potentially-related [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930802/convergency-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cscnn).

Comment: The sequence that determines the series does not converge to $0$, so the series cannot converge. For this result, see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665776/convergence-of-the-sequence-frac1n-sinn)

Comment: @JulioPuerta: Thank for the reference. Now I wonder about the one I recall seeing (with $\sqrt{3}$...or perhaps a different square root?).

Comment: The [accepted solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/665832/16078) to the question @JulioPuerta linked to works with $1$ replaced by $\sqrt3$ or indeed by any real number that is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you. I found the result I was looking for in a textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The series under consideration is the following result due to Hardy:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3\sin(n\pi\sqrt{2})}=-\frac{13\pi^3}{360\sqrt{2}}$$

This result can also be found in Titchmarsh's *The Theory of Functions* textbook.

Comment: While I'm happy you found what you were looking for, this answer doesn't actually answer the question as written.

Comment: @GregMartin Indeed, which is why I won't accept it. If you'd like to write up an answer for the question(s) as posed using the resource from the linked question, I'd gladly accept such an answer.