# Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n^2)}{n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin (n^2)}{n}$ converges.

This question was proposed by Dr. Wolfgang Hintzeh here: [Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(k(k-1))}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466339/convergence-of-sum-k-1-infty-frac-sinkk-1k/3466774#3466774)

**My attempt**

I can see that all terms are bounded by $\frac{1}{n}$ but we cannot conclude that all terms are less than some $\frac{1}{n^p},p>1$. And because both Ratio Test and Comparison Test give no information about the convergence, I formed the corresponding integral, but since the Integral Test is not valid for this kind of series, I want to use it to check whether the series converges absolutely.

I constructed the graph of $\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty}\left|\dfrac{\sin (x^2)}{x}\right|dx$:

[image]

> How is that possible for the integral to be less than $0$ on some intervals? What is wrong with my method? Can anybody give me some hints to prove or disprove its convergence?

Comment: It looks unlikely to converge absolutely, I'd expect $|\sin n^2|$ to be equidistributed in the interval $[0,1]$ and so the series to compare unfavourably with $\sum\frac1n$. Proving that seems hard though.

Comment: The engine computes indefinite integral and definite integral in different ways.

Comment: @xbh Ok, then how to calculate the integral? it is hard to evaluate...

Comment: This series has positive terms. I don't understand why you are distinguishing it converging form it converging absolutely. And either way, the Integral Test doesn't apply, because $\sin^2(x)/x$ is not a decreasing function.

Comment: @alex.jordan It has both negative and positive terms.

Comment: @KevinSong I might rewrite the summand as $\frac{\sin (n^2)}{n}$ (with parentheses) to avoid confusion with the more common expression $\sin^2 n = (\sin n)^2$.

Comment: A harmonic series with random signs converges with probability 1, so this sequence probably converges. No idea how to prove that, though.

Comment: @TravisWillse ok, i edited it.

Comment: Sorry, I saw $\sin(x)^2$ instead of $\sin(x^2)$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer the question in the title of the post, the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n}
$$
converges conditionally - but the proof relies on some more advanced concepts.

Actually, this is a special case of a problem [solved on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248199/conditional-convergence-of-sum-n-geq-1-frac-sinpnn). More precisely, on that page they show a more general result, which states that for a wide range of $x\in\mathbb R$ the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi xn^2)}{n}
$$
is conditionally convergent. Your question is the special case $x=1/2\pi$, which happens to satisfy the crucial condition on $x\in\mathbb R$ for the result to apply.

The exact condition on $x\in\mathbb R$ is that $x$ is not a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number). Liouville numbers are an extremely rare class of transcendental numbers that have amazingly accurate rational approximations. There is a quantity called the [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) which can be given to any irrational number, and if it takes the value $\infty$ then the number is Liouville (and conversely, if it is finite then the number is non-Liouville). [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404523) gives upper bounds for the irrationality measures of some common numbers, including $\pi$, which has the consequence that $\pi$ is non-Liouville. Since $x=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is obtained from $\pi$ using rational operations, it is therefore non-Liouville as well.

Comment: About that solution on mathoverflow... in it, they use the property of Liouville numbers that there is $n^a < q \leq n$ such that $|2x - p/q| \leq 1/nq$. This looks a little different from the other definitions of Liouville numbers that I have found online. Do you happen to know where I can find this formulation, or at least why ${1 \over \pi}$ satisfies the condition?

Comment: @Zarrax that's a good question, which might be even more valuable directly on the mathoverflow answer itself

Comment: The answer is over three years old so I wasn't sure if it would get a response, but maybe I should still do that. I'm pretty sure ${1 \over \pi}$ satisfies an appropriate approximation property but it's been hard to pin down the right reference.

Answer (score 3):

Proof for divergence of
$$
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}
\newcommand\rme{\mathrm e}
\newcommand\imu{\mathrm i}
\newcommand\diff{\,\mathrm d}
\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}
\renewcommand \epsilon \varepsilon
\newcommand\trans{^{\mathsf T}}
\newcommand\F {\mathbb F}
\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}
\newcommand \N {\Bbb N}
\renewcommand\geq\geqslant
\renewcommand\leq\leqslant
\int_1^{+\infty} \abs {\frac {\sin (x^2)}{x}} \mathrm dx. 
$$
Easy to see $\abs {\sin (x^2)} \geq\sin^2 (x^2) = (1 - \cos (x^2))/2$ since $0 \leq \abs {\sin (u)} \leq 1$.
Then
$$
\int_1^{  +\infty } \frac {\abs {\sin (x^2)}}x \geq \frac 12 \int_1^{+\infty} \frac 1x \diff x  - \frac 12 \int_1^{+\infty} \frac {\cos (2x^2)}x \diff x =: \frac 12( I_1 + I_2). 
$$
Clearly $I_1$ diverges. For $I_2$, via the substitution $u = 2x^2$, or $x = \sqrt {u/2}$,
$$
I_2 = \int_2^{+\infty} \frac {\cos u} {\sqrt {u/2}} \diff \sqrt {u/2} = \int_2^{+\infty} \frac {\cos u} {2u} \diff u, 
$$
and this is convergent by Dirichlet Test. Therefore the original integral is a sum of a *divergent* integral and a *convergent* integral, which shall be divergent as well.

#### Counterexample for integral test when the terms are not decreasing

Consider
$$
f(x) = \frac {\pi x} {1 + (\pi x)^6 \sin^2 (\pi x)}, x \geq 0. 
$$
Then $f$ is nonnegative, and the limit $f(+\infty)$ does not exist, since $f (n) = \pi n \to +\infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Then the series $\sum_1^{+\infty} f(n)$ diverges since a necessary condition for convergence is that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(n) = 0$. But the integral $\int_0^{+\infty} f(x) \diff x$ converges since
$$
\int_n^{n+1} f(x) \diff x = \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac x  {1 + x^6 \sin^2 x} \diff x\leq \frac {2\pi^2}{n^2}, 
$$
for each $n \in \N^*$, then the integral is bounded from above by $\pi^4/3$.

Comment: I thought the question is about the conditional convergence of a sum, not about the integral, but I think I have misread the question. It is very confusing, since the title of the question doesn't seem to match with what is asked in the body of the question.

Comment: @pre-kidney Yes. I cannot guarantee this is what the OP wants since the question is not very clear to me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.